# Принимает за ключ не ту переменную

Tags: python, словари

```
for i in range(len(text_2)):
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    out_text += str(D[i])
```

Словарь:

```
D = {
    1: 'а', 2: 'А', 3: 'б', 4: 'Б', 5: 'в', 6: 'В', 7: 'г', 8: 'Г', 9: 'д', 10: 'Д', 11: 'е',
    12: 'Е', 13: 'ё', 14: 'ж', 15: 'Ж', 16: 'з', 17: 'З', 18: 'и', 19: 'И', 20: 'й', 21: 'к',
    22: 'К', 23: 'л', 24: 'Л', 25: 'м', 26: 'М', 27: 'н', 28: 'Н', 29: 'о', 30: 'О', 31: 'п',
    32: 'П', 33: 'р', 34: 'Р', 35: 'с', 36: 'С', 37: 'т', 38: 'Т', 39: 'у', 40: 'У', 41: 'Ф',
    42: 'ф', 43: 'х', 44: 'Х', 45: 'ц', 46: 'Ц', 47: 'ч', 48: 'Ч', 49: 'ш', 50: 'Ш', 51: 'щ',
    52: 'Щ', 53: 'ъ', 54: 'ы', 55: 'ь', 56: 'э', 57: 'Э', 58: 'ю', 59: 'Ю', 60: 'я', 61: 'Я',
    62: ' '
}
```

Принимает за ключ не значение переменной `i`, а ее порядковый номер.